# JQuery current $(this) object

Tags: jquery, this

Im going to discover how to make menu resposible for small screen. I was trying to find a jQuery code to do so. This code was running perfectly but I need make it more complicated and try to response on current screen width. When I was trying to call mobmenu() with my menuScreen() function I think that I lost current $(this) object because the code stoped running. Can somebody be helpfull.

```
(function($) {                                                                       
    $.fn.mobmenu = function(options) {
        console.log("m1 - The current version of jQuery being used: jquery " + jQuery.fn.jquery);
    return this.each(function(){                                    
                console.log("m1.1 - Waiting for click...");
                //---------- and nothing going on here :-(
                $(this).find("ul.nav > li > .not_active").on("click", function(){

                        console.log("m2 - Menu element cliked");
                        if ($(this).siblings(".nav-child").css("display") == "block") {
                            $(this).siblings(".nav-child").toggle();
                        } else {
                            console.log("m3 else loop");
                            $(this).parents(".nav").find(".nav-child").css("display", "none");
                            $(this).siblings(".nav-child").toggle();
                            console.log("m4 else loop end");
                            };
                            $(this).siblings(".nav-child").find(".not_active").on("click", function() {
                                    if ($(this).siblings(".nav-child").css("display") == "block") {
                                        $(this).parents("li").find("li .nav-child").toggle();
                                    };
                                    if ($(this).siblings(".nav-child").css("display") == "none") {
                                        console.log("m5 - menu 2nd level display before: ", $(this).siblings(".nav-child").css("display"));
                                        $(this).siblings(".nav-child").toggle();
                                        console.log("m6 - menu 2nd level display after: ", $(this).siblings(".nav-child").css("display"));
                                    };                                      
                            });
                }); 
        });                                                                                 
    };
})(jQuery); 

(function($) {                                                                          
    $(document).ready(function() {
            function menuScreen() { 
                console.log("3 - Called menuScreen");
                    console.log("4 - screen.width = ", screen.width,"px");
                    $(this).mobmenu();
                    console.log("5 - Called mobmenu");

            };  
            //-----------------------------------------------
            console.log("1 - Main code START after page ready");
            if ($(window).width() < 400) {
                console.log("2 - Czy < 400px: -> ", screen.width, "px", $(window).width()," px" );
                menuScreen();
            } else {
                console.log("6 - Screen larger than: 400 -> ", screen.width); 
            };
            //-----------------------------------------------
            $(window).on('resize', function() {  
                console.log("7 - Screen resize detected");
                if ($(window).width() < 400) { 
                    console.log("7 - After resize screen", screen.width);
                    menuScreen();                   
                    console.log("8 - menuScreen called");
                } else {
                console.log("9 - Screen after resize operation still larger than: 400 -> ", screen.width);  
                };                  
            });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If you've lost track of `this`, making it *"more complicated"* seems like a terrible idea ?

Comment: Use css media queries for responsive layout

Comment: I have responsive layout done. It is based on bootstrap grid. There is a lot of CSS formatting but for a specific reason (joomla) i was forced to do mobile menu for small devices using jquery. I thought HTML5+CSS+JQUERY means responsive web design. Do I make mistake? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual selector to call your plugin.

The way you are using it now, `this` is not an element

Change

```
$(this).mobmenu();
```

To

```
$('#mobMenuId').mobmenu();
```

Please note however that you are going to be compounding many many click handlers by calling this inside a resize event.

Resize event can be triggered many times a second during manual resize ... and each time you call plugin inside it you will be compounding click listeners on top of existing click listeners

Comment: That is an answer! Thank you for it. I'll try. I've started with jquery 2 months ago and this is obvious that I have  problems.

Comment: You really have right. There is many calls if I resize screen manually. But  - I tried Your answer in code but there is any reaction even if I'm not using resize code. Im going to try anyway.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking to long. $(this).mobmenu(); was perfectly calling funtion before I wrap it in menuScreen function. I was succesfully traversing DOM inside mobmenu function. The problem started when I was implementig menuScreen. I cant find proper $(this) calling it from inside menuScreen. Courious.

Comment: charlietf jsfiddle.net is a good idea but I need some time. I have a lot php generated html code and css. But I'll try.

Comment: really simple to copy html from browser dev tools. Look in live html, right click/copy

Comment: Thanks for all Helpfull Guys! I have found a method. I was so stupid! My code is just a set of jQuery plugins. I've forgotten that I need an $.fn.menuScreen object but not simple function. Somtimes we need to talk to sombody a litlle on our way. Thanks for You for inspiration. Now I can go to bed and rest a litlle.

Comment: I'll put my code here tomorrow when I have it cleaned. Maybe somebody will find it helpfull.